# Adding elements dynamically into 2D array only by using primitives

Tags: java, excel, multidimensional-array, apache-poi

with the below code I need to change Object[][] bookcomments in such a way where I should add elements dynamically into bookcomments, and use this further for writing the content into xlsx file.

PROBLEM : the issue that i am facing here is, I used  **bookComments = new Object[][]{{name,email,phNo,skillset},};** this line is re-initializing my 2D array each and every time.

Your help is highly appreciated !!, Thank you in Advance.

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        // headers of xlsx sheet - hard coded here
        Object[][] bookComments = { { "name", "email", "Mobile number", "skillset" }, };
        Sheet newSheet = workbook.createSheet("org2");
        Iterator it = empSheet.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator itAddress = addressSheet.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator itSkillSheet = skillSheet.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry eSheet = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            String email = null;
            String skillset = null;
            String name = (String) eSheet.getValue();
            String phNo = (String) eSheet.getKey();
            List<String> addressndEmail = addressSheet.get(phNo);
            email = addressndEmail.get(1);
            skillset = skillSheet.get(name);
            bookComments = new Object[][]{{name,email,phNo,skillset},};
            //ArrayUtils.addAll(bookComments, bookComment);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't change the size of an array once created. You either have to allocate it bigger than you think you'll need or accept the overhead of having to reallocate it needs to grow in size. When it does you'll have to allocate a new one and copy the data from the old to the new,Other wise you can use array list instead of an array.

Should initialize the size of array initially

```
String[][] bookComments = new String[intSize][intSize];
```

Assign  values (Use an increment variable in while loop like 'i' )

```
 i++;
 bookComments[i][0]=name;
 bookComments[i][1]=email;
 bookComments[i][2]=phNo;
 bookComments[i][3]=skillset;
```

I don't know your requirement,hope this may help you

Comment: Thank you so much Sreejesh. This is a good approach. Its working for me. Wishing you a great new year 2018 .